# Angular polling with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, promise, restangular

I'd like to poll a backend, using Restangular, until a condition is met. I am using Angular Poller for the polling (https://github.com/emmaguo/angular-poller). It returns a promise.

The code below is correctly performing the polling, but I cannot access the returned data. The console.log in the **then** is not printing.

What is happening here?

```
var myPoller = poller.get(Restangular.one('batches',$routeParams.panel_id), {
     action: 'get',
     delay: 1000,
     arguementsArray: []
  });


  myPoller.promise.then(function(batch){
     $scope.running = batch.batch_status;
     console.log('Status: ' + batch.batch_status);
     if (batch.batch_status === 'complete'){
        myPoller.stop();
     }
  });
```

**UPDATE**

The documentation for Angular Poller refers to a callback.

https://github.com/emmaguo/angular-poller#customize-restangular-poller

```
myPoller.promise.then(null, null, callback);
```

Comment: Where are your null,nulls?

Comment: I'm not really clear on how the callback should work. I can create a function called 'callback' and console.logs work from there, but how do I access the returned data?

Comment: You correctly point out that thge documentation says `....then(null, null, callback)` but your own code is `....then(callback)`. So where are your null,nulls?

Comment: The null,nulls btw are the success and error functions, as described in [The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) at the angular docs. The then function is defined as `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)`.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick. That's what I thought, and I tried to call the successCallBack in my original code, but I guess my syntax was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. For anyone else wanting to use Restangular with Angular Poller, here is my working code.

The part I was stuck on was how to access the returned object from Restangular. Turns out you just assume it is being passed, and reference it in the callback.

A polling stop condition can then be built by looking at the returned data.

```
 var callback = function(batch) {
     console.log("in the callback " + batch.batch_status);
     $scope.running = batch.batch_status;
     if (batch.batch_status.hasOwnProperty('complete')){
        myPoller.stop();
     }

  }


  var myPoller = poller.get(Restangular.one('batches',$routeParams.panel_id), {
     action: 'get',
     delay: 1000,
     arguementsArray: []
  });

  myPoller.promise.then(null,null,callback);
```